# Can devices missing feature X still access old APKs on the Play Store if latest APK requires X?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, apk

I have an already-released android app. If I add a new required feature to a new update, what happens to current users whose devices don't have that feature?

The documentation makes it clear that these users won't see *updates* since their devices aren't supported. But if they delete the app from their phone, and then try to re-download it, will they see the old versions in the Play Store?

As I [understand](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#MultiApks) it, I can't leave the old version of the APK active in the play store since it's filtering on features, not API level or the other requirements. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

The users, as you say, will not see an update to the app who don't have that feature. New users (and people who uninstalled it) who don't have that feature will not be able to install the app. They may see it in the store, but they cannot download it.

The only way I know that you can get around this is to release two different apps: one your updated app with the new required features, and the other an old version not having those features. You should make certain to tell users wheather they will be recieving updates with the other app, and you could even put a link to the old app saying `If you don't have x or y, go here to download the app:`.

Another option is to not require this feature, and to just do it like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="x" android:required="false" />
```

And then you can detect wheather this feature is there in the device, and if so enable some features, if not, disable them.

Comment: They may see it? I was under the impression that play store filtering http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html would stop them seeing things they can't download. Also, any doc links to back up "new users without the feature will not be able to download it"?

Comment: @tenpn If you use Google Play on the web, you will be able to see it, and also (from my experience) sometimes if you search the whole name of the app on the mobile store, you can find it but it's a greyed out install button. I don't have a doc for the second part, but speaking from experience (Nexus 7 w/o front camera can't download apps that need front camera).